# Rails controller to return a whole react app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, integration

I have a Rails API application and a separate standalone React application.

I want to create a controller that returns this whole app to the end user and let the react app consume the API from the dedicated controllers, instead of creating two servers.

How can I do this neatly?

The react app tree is:

- public

  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - manifest.json
- src

  - Assets/
  - Componenets/
  - Views/
  - App.css
  - App.js
  - index.css
  - index.js
  - registerServiceWorkder.js
- README
- package.josn
- package-lock.json

Comment: You probably want to bundle the JS in the asset pipeline. There are tutorials  on how to do this.

Comment: Set this up in your routes. The root path should deliver the client-side app. The rest can be the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very experienced on this matter, but if it would help, this is what I did in my recent project:

- Use / integrate [webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) into your Rails project
- **app/config/routes.rb**:

  ```
  # all JSON requests goes here
  scope constraints: -> (request) { request.format == :json } do
    # all of your Rails API routes goes here
  end

  # all HTML requests goes here,
  # as your react-router should already be able to handle this
  scope constraints: -> (request) { request.format == :html } do
    # this matches ALL paths to bootstrapper action
    match '*path', to: 'application#bootstrapper'
  end

  root 'application#boostrapper'
  ```
- **app/controllers/application_controller.rb**:

  ```
  def bootstrapper
    render template: 'layouts/bootstrapper'
  end
  ```
- **app/views/layouts/bootstrapper.html.erb**

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- YOUR USUAL <head> HERE -->
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- DONT NEED THE <%= yield %> HERE -->
      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'your_react_pack' %>
      <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'your_react_pack' %>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Finally configure your **app/javascript/packs/your_react_pack.js** (This is the entry-point of your React files, and so you'll `import` your React app here) See [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) for details

### Bonus

- Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection is a must! In Rails 5 (or perhaps 4 as well?) you can simply use `Rails.csrfToken()` to get the token in JS, and pass it as a `'X-CSRF-Token'` header when submitting JSON requests to your Rails app. Make sure you have `//= require rails-ujs` in your **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** for you to be able to use `Rails.csrfToken()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a direct write up of how to connect them, it would be a bit lengthy but here is a link that can get you on your way:

1. This link talks about 'create-react-app' which is what you did to create your react application and Rails API.

https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-get-create-react-app-to-work-with-your-rails-api/

In general, all you do is create 'Rails API' application and render json with your controllers and use React fetch/axios to connect to the your Rails API